# Really annoying big font in VMWare Fusion 7

Tags: fonts, virtualization, vmware, macosx

I don't know where I was supposed to ask this question. I'm running an Ubuntu 14.04 VM on VMWare Fusion 7 and MAC OS 10.10.2. And I don't know why but it doesn't look good:

For example on google chrome:

[image]

It doesn't look good, plus I have to zoom the page in order to see it well:

[image]

My resolution: `2560x1600 (16:10)`
Size of menus and title: `1.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same problem on my IMac Retina and here is how I fixed it: 
go to "Virtual Machine", "settings", "Display", then check box "Use full resolution for Retina dislay"

Everything turns beautiful...  Enjoy!